# babel 3.42 (and later?): "nohyphenation" and languages that use "zerohyph.tex" aren't recognized

Tags: babel, hyphenation

Babel 3.42 seems to show some inconsistent behaviour with the dummy language `nohyphenation` and some other languages such as `farsi` which can be chosen within macros such as `\foreignlanguage` to avoid hyphenation in a short piece of text.

It gives this warning:

> Package babel Warning: Unknown language `nohyphenation'. Either you have misspelled its name, it has not been installed, or you requested it in a previous run. Fix its name, install it or just rerun the file, respectively. [...]

The manual says

> ...provided that in language.dat the ‘language’ nohyphenation is defined by loading zerohyph.tex"

and this is indeed my case: `nohyphenation` is defined in `language.dat`, and its corresponding file, `zerohyph.tex`, is also in the TeXLive path and reported by `kpsewhich`.

If I replace `nohyphenation` with some other language, say `dutch`, no warnings appear. The only difference I've found between the two languages is that `zerohyph.tex` is in the directory `generic\hyphen` whereas the one for dutch is in `generic\hyph-utf8\loadhyph`. (Neither the package `hyphen` or `hyph-utf8` are directly called in the preamble.)

If I replace `nohyphenation` with something that's undefined in `language.dat`, say `doesntexist`, then I get an error rather than a warning:

> Package babel Error: You haven't defined the language doesntexist yet.

The same problem exists for `farsi` and all languages in `language.dat` that rely on `zerohyph.tex`.

Must I give some extra option to the `babel` package so that `nohyphenation` is recognized?

I'm using TeXLive 2020 on Windows 10. Babel is called with just the `main=british` option.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[main=british]{babel}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\foreignlanguage{dutch}{some text not in Dutch.}

\foreignlanguage{nohyphenation}{some text not to be hyphenated.}

\foreignlanguage{farsi}{some text not in Farsi.}

\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please show a minimal example of code that fails?

Comment: @egreg Good point, I added it now.

Comment: `language.dat` and `babel` are related, but they are different things. The fact there is a set of hyphenation patterns for a language with a certain name doesn't mean there is a language in `babel` with the same name. A language in `babel` defines captions, date, typographical rules and so on, so selecting `nohyphenation` with `\foreignlanguage` doesn't make much sense. Use `hyphenrules` (the explanation you've copied about  `nohyphenation` is, in fact, in the paragraph about this environment; see also the note in sec. 1.1 about what “language” means).

Comment: Thank you @JavierBezos, and thank you for maintaining that useful package. I agree about `nohyphenation`, but the same problem appears with other languages such as `farsi`, which do make sense in a `\foreignlanguage` macro.

Comment: As I said, the fact there is a set of hyphenation patterns for a language with a certain name doesn't mean there is a language in babel with the same name. For example, there is no language named `german-x-2019-04-04`. Try with `persian` (which works only with `xetex` and `luatex`, except if you load the package `arabi`, with `farsi` as a class/package option).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I slightly modify your code to

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[british]{babel}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\foreignlanguage{dutch}{some text not in Dutch.}

\foreignlanguage{nohyphenation}{some text not to be hyphenated.}

\begin{hyphenrules}{nohyphenation}some text not to be hyphenated.\end{hyphenrules}

\end{document}
```

and compile it with TeX Live 2012 I get no warning. If I try with TL 2013, I get the warnings

```latex
Package babel Warning: You haven't loaded the language dutch yet
(babel)                I'll proceed, but expect unexpected results.
(babel)                Reported on input line 9.


Package babel Warning: You haven't loaded the language nohyphenation yet
(babel)                I'll proceed, but expect unexpected results.
(babel)                Reported on input line 11.
```

Note that nothing is reported for line 13, which is (and has been for a long time) the proper way to use `nohyphenation`. With the current TeX Live, the warning is

```latex
Package babel Warning: Unknown language `nohyphenation'. Either you have
(babel)                misspelled its name, it has not been installed,
(babel)                or you requested it in a previous run. Fix its name,
(babel)                install it or just rerun the file, respectively. In
(babel)                some cases, you may need to remove the aux file.
(babel)                I'll proceed, but expect wrong results.
(babel)                Reported on input line 11.
```

because now `babel-dutch.tex` is loaded and no warning about the language not loaded in the options is given (which is possibly something to be thought about).

Comment: Thank you, yes I get no warnings with hyphenrules, so I'll modify my code accordingly. My use of nohyphenation within \foreignlanguage dates back to TeXLive 2008, I believe...

Comment: But note that the same warning appears with, say, `farsi` and some other languages in `language.dat` that refer to `zerohyph.tex` – and that it would make sense to use within `\foreignlanguage`.

Comment: I've accepted your answer, which works for me. But possibly I should report this as a bug.